# XML dateTime with time zone

Tags: xml, datetime, xslt, xpath

Is there a XPath or XSLT function which can be used to convert a date like "2015-10-15 11:45:46 EDT" to convert into valid XML dateTime format with timezone?

Comment: Can you be certain you know what the time zone abbreviation means?  Maybe so for "EDT", but what about other values?  For example, does the C in "CST" stand for Central, Cuba, or China?  Does the B in "BST" stand for British or Bangladesh?  Does the I in "IST" stand for India or Ireland?  Many other examples...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is the right way but the following function takes the part of your date string without the timezone and converts it to an `xs:dateTime` by placing a `T` between the `xs:date` and `xs:time` part, then it formats that to a format the `parse-ietf-date` can parse, including the previous timezone part in the data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:function name="mf:parse-date" as="xs:dateTime">
      <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
      <xsl:variable name="components" select="tokenize($input, ' ')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="dateTimeWithoutTz" select="xs:dateTime($components[1] || 'T' || $components[2])"/>
      <xsl:variable name="ietf-date" as="xs:string"
        select="format-dateTime($dateTimeWithoutTz, '[FNn,3-3], [D01] [MNn,3-3] [Y0004] [H01]:[m01]:[s01] ' || $components[3], 'en', (), ())"/>
      <xsl:sequence select="parse-ietf-date($ietf-date)"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="date">
      <date input="{.}">{mf:parse-date(.)}</date>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

At https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2D5 that gives the result `2015-10-15T11:45:46-04:00` for the input `2015-10-15 11:45:46 EDT`.

It might be easier to construct a mapping from known timezone names to offsets and then convert your input directly to an `xs:dateTime` by replacing the space between date and time with a `T` and the timezone name with the corresponding offset.